# Black Screen Around App?

Tags: ios, uiview, screen

I have an application that I am making and when I start it it appears with a black strip at the top and bottom of the App. I looked this up and it appears that maybe it is not optimized for the newest versions of xcode.

I'm Using X-code 7 beta 5 & Swift 2.0. Can Someone Please Help me set it back to normal? Should I start a new app and then import the code and everything over to that one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely that you have a very old project that is not even optimized for iPhone 5 screens, never mind 6 and up. Just start a new project with Xcode 7 and drag your header and implementation files over to your new project.